# The name 'contextRequestMethod' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, middleware

i am following a tutorial online and the code i have typed is exactly the same but I am getting a few errors,
one being,

```
using System.Web;


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{

    
    if (contextRequestMethod == HttpMethodsGet && contextRequestQuery["custom"] == true)
    {
        string contextResponseContentType = "text/plain";
        await contextResponseWriteAsync("Custom Middleware \n");
    }

        await next();

});


app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.Run();
```

Error   CS0103  The name 'contextRequestMethod' does not exist in the current context   Core    C:\Users\djone\Desktop\Programming\CSharp\Core\Program.cs   11  Active

i have tried letting VS edit the code but i have come to the conclusion the guy's code as got some additional dependencies or something installed on his solution

Comment: It looks like the dots are missing. It supposed to be `context.Request.Method` and `context.Request.Query`. Also `context.Response.WriteAsync`.

Comment: i was just going to post that same answer after reading another post, very similar to this, thanks for the answer though, every bit of help needed when i am just learning to code.